# Portrait mode notification icon

Tags: 7.0-nougat, notification-icons, auto-rotation

If you disable auto-rotate (i.e., force portrait mode), a notification icon shows up. It looks like the vibrate notification, except without the vibration lines. Inside Settings -> Display -> System icons, I can disable other notification icons like the battery, battery %, wifi, etc., but not this one.

Is there any other way to disable this notification, or even other ones not present in System icons?

I'm on Android 7.0, Sony Xperia X Compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull down the statusbar twice, press and hold the gear in the upper right corner for 5 seconds - then exit and go to settings: now the "System UI Tuner" is there. Disable auyo totate notification.